# Interact with highcharts using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'd like to create an HTML menu to let users show/hide parts of a pie chart on click on the menu options.

Here you can see an example of the chart I want to use:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyzj8cvp/

I'd like to let users click on the menu options and perform the same action of a click on the legend items.

I've tought about use a jQuery trigger `$(".e").trigger("click")` but the legend items have not an ID or a class to select them...

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it using `index()` and `eq()` but you have to maintain the sequence in both:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".menu li").click(function(){

            $(".highcharts-legend-item").eq($(this).index()).trigger("click");

  })
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyzj8cvp/1/

Comment: nice but if I click the legend items the menu item is not clicked, any idea?

Comment: you have to handle that same way, the way we are doing on menu click

Comment: if I add an event handler to the svg element it does not work.. :\

Answer (score 1):

Using Highcharts, specifically for pie charts, you can do this with `point.setVisible(boolean)`. This is because each legend item for a pie chart is a single point (not a series). For example:

```
$('.firefox').click(function() {
    var point = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[0];
    point.setVisible(!point.visible);
});

$('.ie').click(function() {
    var point = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[1];
    point.setVisible(!point.visible);
});
```

When clicking on one of your menu items (`.firefox` or `.ie`) we first locate the relevant point (you could organize these for easier access). Then we toggle the `setVisible` between `true` and `false`.

See these demonstrations:

- [JSFiddle based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/nyzj8cvp/2/)
- [JSFiddle with ID based on Pawels advice](http://jsfiddle.net/nyzj8cvp/3/)

Comment: There are not nicer solutions without be based on order of items so?

Comment: You can add for each of points ID, then call simple `chart.get(point_id)` and you will get corresponding point.